# Can I create a CollectionProperty of brushes?

Tags: python, sculpting, properties

I want to create a collection property with certain sculpt brushes. Can this be done? I tried:

```
WindowManager.coll = CollectionProperty(type=bpy.types.Brush)
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
TypeError: CollectionProperty(...) expected an RNA type derived from ID
Exception in module register(): '/home/antoni4040/Documents/blender-2.79-linux-glibc219-i686/2.79/scripts/addons/Advanced_Brushes/__init__.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/blender-2.79-linux-glibc219-i686/2.79/scripts/modules/addon_utils.py", line 350, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/blender-2.79-linux-glibc219-i686/2.79/scripts/addons/Advanced_Brushes/__init__.py", line 23, in register
    registerBrushSelectionPanel()
  File "/home/antoni4040/Documents/blender-2.79-linux-glibc219-i686/2.79/scripts/addons/Advanced_Brushes/Brush_Menu/Brush_Menu.py", line 120, in registerBrushSelectionPanel
    WindowManager.coll = CollectionProperty(type=bpy.types.Brush)
ValueError: bpy_struct "WindowManager" registration error: coll could not register
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make a [PropertyGroup](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#collection-example) with a brush type member.**

Can use a pointer property to point to an ID type, in this case a brush. `brush = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Brush)`

```
import bpy

# Assign a collection
class SceneSettingItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Test Prop", default="Unknown")
    brush = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Brush)

bpy.utils.register_class(SceneSettingItem)

bpy.types.Scene.brushes = \
    bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SceneSettingItem)

print("Adding All Brushes")

for brush in bpy.data.brushes:
    my_item = bpy.context.scene.brushes.add()
    my_item.name = brush.name
    my_item.brush = brush
```

Python console check after running script above.

```
>>> C.scene.brushes['Twist'].brush
bpy.data.brushes['Twist']
```

Comment: Thanks. But to be totally honest, I was also wondering if I could add such a collection property to a template_ID_preview and get a preview with some custom brushes. Could you please tell me (if you know) if I'm on the right track or if I'm going the wrong way?